# Java – Test Application won't Connect with the Server via Public IP

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, ip

I have been building an application for a few months now, and it seems to be able to connect to its server, but only as long as I use my private IP address.  As soon as I change the address to my public IP, I get the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /108.29.314.30 (port 8001): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

This is the socket on the application (which, again, works only with my private IP)

```
clientSocket = new Socket("108.29.314.30", 8001);
```

This is connection loop of the server:

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8001);

    while(serverIsRunning) {

        Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
        Thread connection = new Thread(new ServerConnection(connectionSocket));
        connection.start();
    }
```

Can anyone tell my why this is not working?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: private address is not working ? what is working, using the ip=localhost ? what do you mean by private and public addresses rfc1918 addresses ?

Comment: the port you are requesting is not allowing you to connect...check firewall settings

Comment: My firewall settings tell me that all incoming connections are allowed.